# android:layout_alignParentRight="true" - editText still appears on the left of the layout - Android / XML

Tags: xml, android-relativelayout, android, android-xml

I have a RelativeLayout with two editText fields I'm attempting to align with the right side of the screen. What what I've seen and what I remember android:layout_alignParentRight="true" should do the trick but for some reason they still appear on the left side of the screen.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Last Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email Address"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Phone Number"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="USERNAME"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="PASSWORD"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

    android:scaleType="fitXY" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Last Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email Address"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Phone Number"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:hint="USERNAME"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:hint="PASSWORD"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Appearance After Edit:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of the editTexts is match_parent, and their text is align on the left. Therefore, even though the edit text is on the right, it starts at the left (because it fills the width of its parent). Change the width to something smaller, and you'll see that your code works .

Comment: They still are not displayed on the right side of the screen (I posted an updated screenshot w code)

Comment: Euhm, the username is on the right..? You just made it too small. Try 250dp for instance.